# FlatList not scrolling on Android in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist that scrolls fine on iOS but not on Android, with Android it will not scroll at all which means a user cannot access any data if it fills past the screen height

I have created a Snack https://snack.expo.dev/@richlewis14/full-screen-flatlist which will show the issue I'm facing.

I'm also interested in knowing why this works on iOS but not Android

Comment: Rich, are you able to edit this question to make it self-contained (and thus on-topic)? I can help you reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your Snack. It was missing `flex: 1` on the component view and also replaced `<Box />` with native `<SafeAreaView />` component. I put different background color (orange and yellow) to show what I modified.

https://snack.expo.dev/GhDjDDJ1Z

Comment: Could you add what exactly was going wrong? I think it would benefit others (including myself) with a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: Will do as soon as i get it working on my app, just playing with the changes now :-)

Comment: Jeaf, could you amend this answer such that the key piece of code appears in the answer itself? This is not quite a "link only answer" but I wonder if it is close.